# Bash Script total sum of a column when another column equals to an input value

Tags: bash, shell-script, files

I am having a csv file with Header. I would like to create a bash script without using AWK to calculate the sum of let's say the 6th column if the variable on the column 13 equals to an input that I will pass via CMD.

File looks like:

```
IDENTIF,RIVER,LOCATION,ERECTED,PURPOSE,LENGTH,LANES,CLEAR-G,T-OR-D,MATERIAL,SPAN,REL-L,TYPE
E2,A,25,1819,HIGHWAY,1037,2,N,THROUGH,WOOD,SHORT,S,WOOD
E7,A,27,1840,HIGHWAY,990,2,N,THROUGH,WOOD,MEDIUM,S,WOOD
E16,A,25,1859,HIGHWAY,1030,2,N,THROUGH,IRON,MEDIUM,S-F,SUSPEN
```

So I would like for example if I execute script.sh WOOD , to print the sum of the 6th columns for the values in column 13 that equal to WOOD.

I have seen many solutions using AWK and solving it immediately. I was hoping how would you do the same without it.

Code I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

skip_line = 0
total_length = 0
while IFS=, read -r -a fields 
do
if [ $skip_line eq 0 ]
then
  skip_line = $(($skip_line + 1))
  continue
fi

if [ ${fields[12]} == $1 ]
then
    total_length = $(($total_length + ${fields[5]}))
fi
done < file.csv

echo "$total_length"
```

Comment: The header seems to be missing from the data. Also, why can't you use awk, a very typical and standard UNIX tool?

Comment: I am practising on shell scripting and I am very beginner. I''ll update the headers.

Comment: OK. As long as you understand that this is not something you should do with a shell script (it is slow, and very hard for no reason). So, what do you have so far? What have you tried? Which part of this is giving you trouble?

Comment: `while IFS=, read -r -a fields; do ...; done < file.csv` is the key piece of the solution

Comment: by using -a fields you are passing it as an array to fields? For example $fields[6] will give me the value of the 6th column?

Comment: ${fields[6]} .. thats why it was not printing

Comment: ... @user440826 bash arrays are zero indexed, so the 6th field will be `${fields[5]}`

Comment: I have added the code I tried

Answer (score 0):

SMOP.

First, use `grep` to select the lines, use `cut` to extract the field, and sum the values.

**Untested**

```
#!/bin/bash
pat="$1"
export total=0
grep ",$pat," file.txt |\
  cut -d, -f6 |\
  while read num ; do
    total=$total + $num
  done
echo "$total"
```

Comment: i run it as ./script.sh WOOD. It prints +:command not found.

Comment: now it justs prints me zero.

Comment: I've posted my code above too but it hits error

Comment: My script had an error on if condition. I did not let space [ condition ] as it needs to be.  But now it says unary expression expected in my first IF condition.

Answer (score 0):

Before considering doing it this way, please see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Nevertheless, your attempt is close (one obvious issue is the whitespace around the `=` in your `total_length` assignment).

```
#!/bin/bash

sum=0
while IFS=, read -a fields; do
  if [[ ${fields[12]} = "$1" ]]; then
    (( sum += fields[5] ))
  fi
done < file.csv

printf 'sum: %d\n' "$sum"
```

You can shorten the `if..then..fi` using short-scircuit logic if you prefer ex.

```
[[ ${fields[12]} = "$1" ]] && (( sum += fields[5] ))
```

There's no need to skip the header line explicitly since it will fail the `${fields[12]} = "$1"` test.

Comment: owo, yeah it worked! thank you!

Comment: Perfect Explanation! thanks again.